# Do C++ abstract classes need to obey the rule of five?

Tags: c++, rule-of-three

When implementing an abstract class like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Does this interface have to obey the rule of five i.e. do I have to add a copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor and move assignment operator?

I'd figure that an instace of type `Base` can not be instantiated due to the pure virtual member function and thus providing default implementations for the other special member functions might serve no real purpose.

Is there any use-case/example that would require me to provide the other special member functions?

Comment: How would you implement those constructor/operators? :P

Comment: You `default`ed your destructor, means you're telling the compiler to generate one. It should be no different to when you just do nothing.

Comment: @KillzoneKid But I guess the intent is that the destructor be virtual.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I meant it should not affect how you use the rule of three, five etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must a c++ interface obey the rule of five?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49961811/2311167). However this question does not have an answer yet. Also possible duplicate of [Abstract class, copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5593168/2311167) as the former rule of three has become the rule of five in C++11.

Comment: in this case `Rule of zero` should be respected.

Comment: @MarekR So in order to respect the rule of zero but still keep a virtual destructor I'd need to either default or delete all the missing constructors/operators? I saw something along those lines in [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#example-good-5) but I was wondering whether this also applies (and what use it has) if the base class has a pure virtual member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"abstract" is irrelevant here. A class needs its own copy constructor, copy assignment operator, etc. if it has data that won't be properly copied by the default versions. Full stop. The presence or absence of pure virtual functions does not change this. Your example doesn't have any data, so doesn't have an issue here.

Comment: It would make sense to make copy-assignment protected though. That way, anybody trying to do the assignment will be stopped.

Comment: @Deduplicator — there are many things that may or may not be important depending on the **role** that a class is **designed** to fill. Being abstract is not a role; it is a tool, and its use does not in any way suggest limits on copying.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is the contrary. I would consider deleting copying and assignment of a class that is supposed to be only an interface class to avoid slicing. Consider

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class D1 : public Base {
    int i;
public:
    ~D1() override {}
};

class D2 : public Base {
    int i;
    double d;
public:
    ~D2() override {}
};
```

you could write something like this

```
vector<Base> vec;
D1 d;
  D2 e;
  vec.push_back(d);
  vec.push_back(e);
```

. You would try to squeeze an object of size D2 into a much smaller object of type base. By deleting copy and assignment you do prevent the user or yourself doing that.

Comment: `>>you could write something like this` Your base class is not an abstract class, but OP's one is. `D1 d; D2 e;` would not be possible

Comment: I apologize. That is quite correct but it does not invalidate the problem mentioned.